# Caching Issue with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

After pushing some changes to a React app and deploying it, I navigated to the site (e.g. https://www.somereactapp.com) and the changes are not shown.

Subsequently I refreshed the page and the updates are shown in the app and it works fine.

However after the refresh I went back to type out the same site https://www.somereactapp.com in the address bar and press enter, it reverted back to the old page again.

Am unable to find out why this is so on google chrome

Comment: if you had serviceworker it may be related to that, also are you using hash naming in app.js ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this happens if the index page does not have a no-cache header. When we do not have the no-cache header, browser tries to cache index.html and does not know about the new version of the app.

However after the refresh, I went back to type out the same site https://www.somereactapp.com in the address bar and press enter, it reverted back to the old page again.  --> Never come across this, curious to find out the solution.